# How to find the Form that hosts a particular a Winforms Control within the Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to be able to access whatever Form hosts my control within the code of my Control, so like:

```
myControl.ParentForm
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`FindForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx) method of the control:

```
Form parent = myControl.FindForm();
```

Comment: keep in mind this only works if the Form has been added by the designer. If you add the control dynamically you need to ensure that the Parent Form is correctly set otherwise FindForm() will return null!!!